# Speed up document update from list of dicts with Pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

I'm trying to create some Mongo documents starting from a list of dictionaries, like this one:

```
dictlist = [ dict1, dict2, dict3 ]
```

Where the generic dict is something like:

```
dict1 = { 'Id': 1, 'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2' }
```

Each dict in the list has the same keys.

Then I'm using this for loop in order to put each dict on Mongo.

```
import datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient

database = MongoClient(mongo_connection_string)
coll = database.collection

for idx, record in enumerate(dictlist):
    time_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()[:-3]
    document_matches = coll.count_documents(record)
    id = record['Id']
    
    if ( document_matches == 0 ): # Document is not already present
        coll.update_one({'Id': id}, {'$set': record}, upsert=False)
        coll.update_one({'Id': id}, {'$set': {'DocumentUpdatedAt': time_now}}, upsert=False)
```

The thing is working, but is slow. I'm wondering if there is any different approach that can speed up the process.

Comment: Isn't checking existence and inserting if not preset already THE actual purpose of upsert ? If yes, why are you checking before inserting. Why not just do the upsert ? (or am I missing something?)

Comment: So, your update logic is: 1. `'Id'` value must already exist in the collection; 2. If any of the other fields in `dict1`/`record` are different than what's already in the document, then update the document with the new value(s); 3. Otherwise do nothing.  Correct?

Comment: _"I'm trying to create some Mongo documents"_  Won't your update logic only possibly update a document and **never** _create_ (i.e., insert/upsert) a document?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `time_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()` rather than your current string?  `pymongo` will [translate python datetimes](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#documents) to [MongoDB Date type](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/bson-data-types-date/) which are more convenient (and probably more performant) for filtering, sorting, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try `document_matches = coll.estimated_count_documents(record)`.

Problem with `count_documents()` is it loops through all the records, and you are doing it in a for loop. This operation alone takes time and resources if you consider a large collection.

Ref link: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.estimatedDocumentCount/

And try to update the collection in a single line for ease of computing, as you mentioned - "*Each dict in the list has the same keys.*"

```
coll.update({'Id': id}, {'$set': {
    'Id': record['Id'],
    'key1': record['value1'],
    'key2': record['value2'],
    'DocumentUpdatedAt': time_now,
 }}, upsert=True)
```

Comment: The OP used `'DocumentUpdatedAt'`.  Using his update logic, an `upsert` will never be done, correct?  I.e., `'Id'` must exist and have the correct value already.

Comment: His goal was to just update and not create duplicates, so he opted for `upsert = False` and checking for possible matches before, doing it twice technically. but as he mentioned his `Id` it is not required.

Comment: That may be his intention, but that's not what his code does.  `document_matches` checks for a match on all fields in `record`, not just `"Id"`. _"he mentioned his `Id` it is not required"_  Where does he mention this?  He also has no mention of `'DocumentCreatedAt'`.